# CSS change li color to a color

Tags: css, colors, html-lists

I am creating a menu in HTML, which is like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
    <li>item4</li>
</ul>
```

I don't want to make `item1` etc. an `a` element, but I want to have the same color on my `li` as I would have with an `a`. I tried using `blue` but the color would be different than my `a` would be. I'm using Firefox (last version) and the only people using/seeing this use firefox.

How can I get the color of my `li's` to EXACTLY the same color as my `a's` would have?

Edit:

It was my own mistake. The CSS of the website gave the a tag a different color by default. Didn't know about that.

Comment: Write your 'a' color value to li. like  ul li {color:#----)

Comment: Inspect element on an `a` tag in firefox to get the exact color code.

Comment: Thanks Bas, appearantly the a tag has given a different color. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your CSS to mimic the `<a>`

```
li   
    {
    color:#0000EE;
    }
```

This is the standard link color for most browsers (should be with FF as well)

Comment: Thanks but it was my fault, appearantly the a tag has been given a different color.

Comment: Then change the default link colors and adjust the <li> accordingly. Appreciate the "Mark as Answer". ;-)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```css
li{
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<li>Item One</li>
<li>Item Two</li>
```

This must help. After clicking a link in html, that link shall become 'visited' link. So, some color maybe changed.

Answer (score 1):

The default blue used by Firefox on an hypertext link has this hexadecimal value : #0000ee.

You should try :

li { color: #0000ee; }

Comment: Try to format your answer some and indicate where to put this code, thanks for answering on SO.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set same color for both 'li' and anchor tag using css.
use the below css to set your favourite colour.

```
li
{
color:blue;
}
a
{
color:blue;
}
```

i hope it may help you.